# null object reference when creating a dialog popup

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

So this is my code below but it keeps giving me an error saying..

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.getLocationOnScreen(int[])' on a null object reference.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.info_about){

            return false;
        }
        if (id == R.id.info_help){
            View anchorView = findViewById(R.id.info_help);

            View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_help_acitivity, null);
            PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            TextView tv = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.help_popup);
            popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
            popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());

            int[] location = new int[2];
            anchorView.getLocationOnScreen(location);

            popupWindow.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY,
                    location[0], location[1] + anchorView.getHeight());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So basically this happens when I click on the menu item I want a little popup or dialog to appear.

How do I fix this, because I did initialize it I am just extremely frustrated with it. Very new to android studio.

Comment: please show how your anchorView is defined and initialized

Comment: where is anchorView = findViewById.... ?

Comment: are you sure             ```View anchorView = findViewById(R.id.info_help);```
this does not remain null?